# Java create method in Interface and change the parameter type

Tags: java, parameters, overloading, overriding

How do I create an interface that when Overridden can have different types? Sometimes I would like the method to accept an item of type 'HtmlPage' and other times I would like it to take the type 'Document'. Later these could change to even more types.

**Example:**

```
public interface MyInterface{
   void checkThis() throws Exception;

   Output Show(Input input, String url) throws Exception;
}

public class HeadLevel extends MyInterface<HtmlPage,String>{
   Output scrape(HtmlPage page, String url) throws Exception;
}

public class MyClass implements HeadLevel<Output>{
   @Override 
   public void checkThis(Document page, String url){

   }
}
```

I am thinking something like this should be achievable. I have tried looking around using keywords 'Overload' and 'Override' in my searches but cannot find something that can work like this. As you can see 'MyClass' has Overridden the method and has defined the parameters being used.

Comment: First of all your syntax is wrong. Secondly Class can extends Another class and not the interface and Class actually implement the interface.

Comment: It is just a general similarity to my project.

Comment: This is technically impossible, as `checkThis(Document, String)` does not and cannot override `checkThis()`. However, if you tell us what you're trying to accomplish with this, we might be able to figure out a workaround.

Comment: as @Zircon mentioned, it is not possible to "override" a method when changing the parameters (since they are part of the method's signature; note that in the Java language the return value is not part of the signature, in the JVM, however, it is). This smells like an [XY-problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), so please describe what you want to achieve rather than showing your approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It feels that you are trying to force the code to solve a problem that you don't understand clearly. I like to step back and think about the connections between components and improve my design in such situations.

Maybe think along the lines that an HtmlPage is a Document. So, if you
extend an HtmlPage with a Document (`public class HtmlPage extends Document`). When an Interface method accepts Document, it will take HtmlPage. Assuming that you have control over the relationship between Document and HtmlPage, in other words, you are not using a third-party library. Once that is done, a method won't need to operate on two unrelated concepts.

I' am not clear about the definition of your problem, better naming might have helped, either way, a potential solution might look like this:

```
interface MyInterface{
    <K extends Document> void checkThis(K htmlPage) throws Exception;

    Output Show(Input input, String url) throws Exception;
}

class HeadLevel implements MyInterface{
    public <K extends Document> void checkThis(K htmlPage) throws Exception
    {
        // Do something
    }

    public Output Show(Input input, String url) throws Exception{
        return new Output();
    }

    public <K extends Document> Output scrape(K htmlPage, String url) throws Exception
    {
        return new Output();
    }
}

class MyClass extends HeadLevel{

    public MyClass() throws Exception
    {
        checkThis(new HtmlPage());
        checkThis(new Document());
    }

    public <K extends Document> void checkThis(K htmlPage) throws Exception
    {
        super.checkThis(htmlPage);
    }
}

class Document{

}

class HtmlPage extends Document
{

}
```

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html

Answer (score 0):

In this case you don't need any interface, it's not possible to do what you want, you need to understand the concept of interfaces before use it.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/interface.html

Comment: Is there any way i van accomplish this with an interface?

Comment: Or perhaps an alternative that would similar?

Comment: Why do you want to use interfaces? What do you really want to do, explain your problem.

Comment: I want to have a method that i can change the parameters. So i would have default parameters and then be able to change them. Similar to have a metho that calculates the area for a square taking in integer length and integer width but then for a triangle you can override and change the parameters for a double radious and double height. For example

Comment: First thing: you are wronged about the concept of "OVERRIDE", to override a method means you copy the same signature (same return, same name, same parameters) and implements what's between the brackets.

Comment: I know Ovverride doesnt do that i am only using it as example because i do not know what to call the implementation i need

Comment: It's impossible to do what you want, you really need different methods, I'm sorry.

Comment: @Renan [The return type is not part of the signature in Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.2). If it were, you could have two method with identical name and argument list, but different return types.

Comment: @L1ghtk3ira one idea that comes to mind would be an `Parameters` interface, which you pass as an argument to your method. For a `Square` the `calculate(Parameters param)` would check that `params instanceof SquareParams` (which implements that interface), while for a `Triangle`, the `calculate(Parameters param)` would check that `params instanceof RectangleParams` (which also implements the `Parameters` interface). You could get rid of the `instanceof`-calls by introducing some generic types.

Comment: @Turning85 you are right about the method signature, the return type is not part of it.

Comment: I have added an answer that works the way I wanted. I apologize for the confusion as I did not fully understand what I wanted. Thank you for your criticism as it did help me question myself and lead me to an answer that works.

Answer (score 0):

The implementation I was looking for turned out to not exist however there is a better way to be able to do what I was looking for using Input and Output.

```
public interface MyInterface<Input, Output> {
   void checkThis(Input input, Output output) throws Exception;

   Output Show(Input input, String url) throws Exception;
}

public class HeadLevel extends MyInterface<HtmlPage,String>{
   Output scrape(HtmlPage page, String url) throws Exception;
}

public class MyClass implements HeadLevel<Output>{
   @Override 
   public void checkThis(Document page, String url){

   }
}
```

It seems the answer was actually under my nose. I misunderstood what Input/Output types are and how you can use them. Input and Output can be of any time that you expect to come in or go out of an application sort of speak.

> Input is any information that is needed by your program to complete
>   its execution.There are many forms that program input may take

Input can take the form of many different types such as HtmlPage, Document, and String. Using input you can Override your method and have your desired types.

You can read more about Input and Output [here](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~cs368-1/JavaTutorial/NOTES/JavaIO_Scanner.html)

Comment: Never declare a method with `throws Exception`.

Comment: Normally, for generic types one uses single upper-case letters, i.e. `I` or `O` so one does not confuse them with actual classes. You could of course make the thrown `Exception` generic as well....: `public interface MyInterface<I, O, E extends Exception>`

Comment: I need the method with thrown exception in my implementation.